# Using Django cycle template tag to number rows

Tags: html, django, loops, django-templates

I am trying to use Django cycle to make my css class have the current table row number in it. I'm trying the following:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' 'row3' %} formset_row">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                       <td>
                           {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                           {% if forloop.first %}
                               {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                   {{ hidden }}
                               {% endfor %}
                           {% endif %}
                           {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                           {{ field }}
                       </td>
                   {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Where my rows are added dynamically using jquery.formset.js https://gist.github.com/vandorjw/f884f0d51db3e7caaecd

For some reason this just gives me

```
<tr class="row1 formset_row">...</tr>
<tr class="row1 formset_row">...</tr>
<tr class="row1 formset_row">...</tr> 
<tr class="row1 formset_row">...</tr>
...
```

1. Why isn't this working?
2. From what I understand this will give me

> row1 row2 row3 row1 row2 row3 row1...

How can I make this continue counting...

> row1 row2 row3 row4 row5 row6 row7...

Comment: Is this HTML rendered by the server or rendered on the client?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why it's not working, but if you want it to continue counting along with the entire loop, you can use

```
class="row{{forloop.counter}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

**In short way **

```
#Create template_tag.py file in your root file
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def modulo(num, val):
    return num % val

``
*then in your html template load {% load template_tags %}*

call it into your table row
<td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31081810)